# Adding data to a list that comes from a website

Tags: python

The problem I'm having is the line where it says **list_titles.append(title)**
at the very bottom, it pulls up the error:
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments. Help please and thank you!
Everytime it loops I want to add the item to the list.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import sys
import pprint
list_titles = []
list_recipes = []


def user_input():

   keyword = input('Please type in dinner ideas and we will give you recipes:')
   return keyword



def get_html():

    keyword = user_input()

    search_page_url = 'http://www.foodnetwork.com/search/'
    search_page = urllib.request.urlopen(search_page_url+keyword+'-') #downloads 
    the webpage
    search_soup = BeautifulSoup(search_page,'html.parser') #create a tree data 
    structure out of html
    ### find all of the 'h3' tags with the class 'm-Med...' ....................................................
    ### and get the link by finding all the 'a' tags
    recipe_blocks = search_soup.find_all('h3',class_='m-MediaBlock__a-
    Headline')# finds h3 html tags with that class

    for recipe in recipe_blocks:
        recipe_url = recipe.find_all('a')[0].get('href') # get link as text
        print(recipe_url)
        page = urllib.request.urlopen('http:'+recipe_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

        for name in soup.find_all('div',class_='parbase assetTitle')
        [0].find_all('span',class_='o-AssetTitle__a-HeadlineText'):

            title = ('  '+name.get_text()
            **list_titles.append(title)**     
            pprint.pprint(list_titles)

        for ingredients in soup.find_all('div',class_='o-Ingredients__m-
        Body')[0].find_all('label',class_='o-Ingredients__a-ListItemText'):

        recipe = ('  '+ingredients.get_text())# gets text from ingredients

        list_recipes.append(recipe) # gets text from ingredients

    pprint.pprint(list_recipes)
```

Comment: whats your input ( food name )?

Comment: a str, it can be anything cookie, potatoe, tofu, chicken, etc, that part works, it extracts perfectly and prints, it just wont add to the list.

Comment: i tried it with "pizza" and after some outputs it was show me : "list index is out of the range" not : TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments!!!

Comment: oohhhh, yeah i think its because the website blocks you from scraping all the material and only allows some to be scraped. I imported time to increment how often it was retrieving information and if you retrieve it at  slower rate you can scrape more items, but shouldn't it still add the items it was able to retrieve from the list?

Comment: maybe...but for me it was ok and i could print list_titles with its elements...:|

Comment: omg -___- okay i got it. THANK YOU SO much!!!

Comment: I added this to the bottom of the above code  

    for ingredients in soup.find_all('div',class_='o-Ingredients__m-Body')[0].find_all('label',class_='o-Ingredients__a-ListItemText'):
    
            recipe = ('  '+ingredients.get_text())# gets text from ingredients

            list_recipes.append(recipe) # gets text from ingredients
    
        pprint.pprint(list_recipes)

right now it seems every line is represented as an item in list_recipes. >>> len(list_recipes)
41 . instead i want len(list_recipes) = 4 to represent 4 total recipes.

Comment: I also added the for loop to the above code so its easier to read. top of page.